React Native Truecaller like popup implementation
I have to implement a feature in React Native App, I am currently developing, in which the feature is when the app gets a silent notification, it needs to open a popup dialog like in truecaller when a call is incoming or outgoing.
I also have to open app's particular screen with params when a button is called from the popup.
Here is the simplified flow,

App get's silent notification -> display truecaller like popup ->
click on button -> open app's particular screen with data

So my question is, in how many ways I can implement this, plus I don't know much about android development, but I can go with it by trial and error,
Please help provide Your views and solutions!
